# How can I debug Xorg failing to hot-plug outputs?

Tags: x11, xorg, video, xrandr

When I connect my laptop to USB-C docking station, Xorg fails to recognize the new, hot-plugged outputs.  This is what xrandr gives me:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.01*+
   1680x1050     60.01  
   1280x1024     60.01  
   1440x900      60.01  
   1280x800      60.01  
   1280x720      60.01  
   1024x768      60.01  
   800x600       60.01  
   640x480       60.01  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

There should be *two additional* DisplayPorts that the docking station provides, but they are missing.

What I know so far:

This is not a HW or driver issue.  I'm sure for two reasons: On the same machine hot-plugging works fine when running Alpine.  And (and more importantly): When I start Xorg only after the docking station is already connected, the outputs are recognized and I can use the attached monitors.

My problem is that I'm not sure where to even start to debug this.  I tried to compare outputs from working (Alpine) and not working (GuixSD) Xorgs, but there was nothing useful (at least to my eyes).  The fact that it is about hot-plugging the whole output (and not just failing to detect monitor or something) makes this fairly niche issue, so I failed to find anything relevant online.  And the fact (as mentioned), that the outputs work just fine if I start X *after* the dock is already connected makes it even weirder.

So, my question is, how can one debug such an issue (but if you know what the issue is, don't hesitate to mention that as well of course :) ).